# Object initialization with 0

Tags: class, object, instance

I wonder, What will happen if I initialize an object with 0.

For example :

```
Class Vehicle
{
}

main()
{
Vehicle v =0;  // or
Vehicle v;
v=0;
}
```

Comment: And what is the language?

Comment: What language is this? Its C-style bracketed but beyond that....

Comment: Agreed, that is NOT C or C++.  **VTC**

Comment: And what exactly you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is C++, this code will generate a compilation error for at least four reasons:

1. Unlike K&R C, C++ does not support functions with implicit return values. The `main` function always returns `int`, and must be explicitly declared as such.
2. The `class` keyword is not capitalized, and the language is case-sensitive. That might just be a typo, but the compiler won't care.
3. The declaration of the `Vehicle` class is invalid. Class declarations must end with a semicolon (after the closing brace `}`).
4. The `Vehicle` class does not define a constructor that accepts an integer (or anything implicitly convertible from `int`), so you cannot initialize a new `Vehicle` object with `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a constructor in Vehicle taking one numeric argument, you'll get a compiler error, because

```
Vehicle v = 0;
```

is the same as

```
Vehicle v(0);
```

In the second case, you need the assignment operator to be defined.

In general, I'd suggest to actually try compiling before asking.

Comment: @CodyGray No, I meant to say the second one. The line `Vehicle v;` defines the variable and constructs it (which is initialization), the line `v = 0;` is consequently an assignment and requires a suitable assignment operator.

Comment: Oh, whoops, I assumed "second case" referred to your second line of code here. Totally forgot about the two examples in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you language is C++ (and corrected to match)

```
class Vehicle
{
};

int main()
{
    Vehicle v = 0;  // or
    Vehicle v;
    v = 0;
}
```

You will not be able to assign 0 to a stack allocated object instance since no overloaded assignment operator exists between `Vehicle`s and `int`s in the case of `v = 0` or suitable constructor in the case of `Vehicle v = 0;`

Perhaps you were thinking of a pointer to a `Vehicle`?

```
 Vehicle* vp = 0;
```

Which would assign memory address `0` (better represented as `NULL` or `nullptr` in C++11) to the pointer variable.